# Onsen UI page not loading correctly after navigation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

I'm developing a mobile application based on the Onsen UI (and PhoneGap + AngularJS).

When I'm navigating through the two html pages of the application, the index loads perfectly, but the next page, which should be shown after login is not usable, the styling is totally off, and no controls are working.

I have an index.html which has the following body:

```
<body>
  <ons-navigator var="myNavigator" page="login.html">
  </ons-navigator> 

  <ons-template id="login.html">
    <ons-page ng-controller="LoginController" id="login">
        <ons-toolbar>
            <div class="center">Log In</div>
        </ons-toolbar>

        <div class="login-form">
            <input type="text" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email">
            <input type="text" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
            <br><br>
            <ons-button modifier="large" class="login-button" ng-click="checkLogin(email,password,spourl)" > Log In</ons-button>
        </div>

    </ons-page>
  </ons-template>

</body>
```

The main.html has the following body:

```
<body ng-controller="AppController">
    <ons-tabbar>
        <ons-tab active="true" page="upcoming_tasks.html">
            ....
        </ons-tab>
        <ons-tab page="settings.html">
            ....
        </ons-tab>
    </ons-tabbar>

    <ons-template id="upcoming_tasks.html">
        <ons-page id="upcoming_tasks">
           ....
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-template id="settings.html">
        <ons-page id="settings">
           ....
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>
```

I have two controllers: 
LoginController which on successful login uses the **myNavigator** to go to main.html (which is in a separate .html file)
AppController which is used in the main.html file for different actions.
Both are loaded from the main.js file, which is included in both files.

If I access both of the files separately, directly from the browser, they work without any problems (http://192.168..../index.html works OK, and also http://192.168.../main.html works OK). 
The error only happens when I'm navigating from the index.html file to the main.html.

What could be the problem? I am fairly new to this whole AngularJS, Onsen UI thing.

I don't really want to "navigate" the browser to main.html, because I am sharing data between the two controllers(the login name and password) using a service, and if the browser reloads the main.html page, the controllers will be initialized and the data will be lost.

Here's a snippet from the main.js file aswell:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);
myApp.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, sharedProperties, Data) {
        $scope.openProtectedPage = function () {
            setTimeout(function() {
                myNavigator.pushPage('main.html');
                //window.location.href = 'main.html';
            }, 1000);

        }

        $scope.checkLogin = function(email,password, url) {
              //check email,pass and url
                   $scope.openProtectedPage();
        }
});
myApp.controller('AppController', function ($scope, $timeout, sharedProperties, Data) {
    $scope.email = sharedProperties.getUser();
    $scope.password = sharedProperties.getPass();
    $scope.url = sharedProperties.getUrl();

    //different functions for loading data and working with it

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few problems here:

1 - `ons-template` must be always located in your `index.html`. Otherwise those pages won't be created by the time you use `pushPage`. Move `upcoming_tasks.html`, `settings.html` and any other template to your index.

2 - Remove `body` tags from your `main.html` page. You just need those in `index.html`, the rest of files (including the ones declared with `ons-template`) must consist only on the actual content that you display inside the navigator.

3 - `ons-navigator` always need an `ons-page` as a child, so wrap your `ons-tabbar` with `ons-page` to avoid possible problems (when you do `pushPage('main.html')` you are including that `ons-tabbar` inside the `ons-navigator` you have in `index.html`).

4 - Perhaps you prefer to use `resetToPage()` instead of `pushPage()` in `openProtectedPage()` so the user cannot go back to login page (it is removed from the page stack).

There are many examples in Onsen UI docs: http://onsen.io/guide/overview.html

Hope it helps!

**Edit**:

`index.html`:

```
<body>

    <ons-navigator var="myNavigator" page="login.html">
    </ons-navigator>

    <ons-template id="login.html">
        <ons-page ng-controller="LoginController" id="login">
            <ons-toolbar>
                <div class="center">Log In</div>
            </ons-toolbar>

            <div class="login-form">
                <input type="text" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email">
                <input type="text" class="text-input--underbar" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
                <br><br>
                <ons-button modifier="large" class="login-button" ng-click="checkLogin(email,password,spourl)" > Log In</ons-button>
            </div>

        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>


    <ons-template id="main.html">
        <ons-page>
            <ons-tabbar>
                <ons-tab active="true" page="upcoming_tasks.html">
                    ....
                </ons-tab>
                <ons-tab page="settings.html">
                    ....
                </ons-tab>
            </ons-tabbar>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-template id="upcoming_tasks.html">
        <ons-page id="upcoming_tasks">
           ....
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

    <ons-template id="settings.html">
        <ons-page id="settings">
           ....
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>

</body>
```

Optionally you can put the content of any `ons-template` you want inside a separated file instead.

Comment: Hi Fran Dios. Thank you for your answer! A couple of follow up questions: 1. if all the ons-templates from main.html will be in index.html why do I still need the main.html file and why do you keep referencing it in the following steps? you're basically saying that all the "pages" should be declared in the index.html file, and the pushPage method would use these templates instead of an actual .html file ?
You see, the index.html file is a simple page, but the main.html file has 3 templates (locally created html things) in it. Wouldn't this be a problem in the whole structure of the UI?

Comment: In `main.html` you have also a tabbar **without** `ons-template`, so I assume you leave that in `main.html` file. If you want to include that also inside `ons-template` then yes, you have to move it to `index.html`. You can also create a file per page as you would normally do without `ons-template`, just don't include `body` tags or anything like that.

Comment: Well the tabbar is referencing the ons-templates from the same file, if you check the names. I found it as an example, actually it's the basic template file from Onsen UI. If it can be done in one single index.html file, where the login page would just disappear after successfull login, and the next 3 pages that were in the main.html file before, would be all properly loaded, then it would be perfect, because then i would be able to keep the variables in the controller.

Comment: You can do that, just need to put the templates in `index.html` as mentioned before. The only difference is that I thought you wanted the tabbar to be in a separate file, but if not you can just include it as an `ons-template` as well. Check the new edit.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I mixed it up real bad, when I had the templates and the separate files, and the navigator. I think I got the hang of it a little better, now! I finally have it working good, now i don't need to save the values from the logincontroller in a cookie, to retrieve them after a reload. Now I just made a service that passes the values. The only thing that still bothers me a little, is that it's kind of sluggish, I took a phonegap project, and copied over the files from the Onsen UI template. Maybe I have to clean it out a little bit.